# Reverse engineering a power supply with more than 600V across the transformer primary

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, reverse-engineering

I'm looking at a power supply board for an LCD TV, specifically a BN44-00878A board from a Samsung UE55KS7500.

[image: Photo of power supply board]

This was originally a repair job, but it turns out the power supply board is fine and the fault was elsewhere.

In the process of eliminating the power supply as the source of a fault, I've done a fair bit of reverse engineering of the supply board. Here's what I've come up with:

[image: Block diagram of the power supply]

The mains comes in, is filtered, then rectified through the large rectifier bridge package, and smoothed by the two caps, creating a DC rail at Vpk of mains - roughly 320V. This is then fed to the two MOSFETs ([Infineon IPAW60R600CE](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPAW60R600CE-DS-v02_02-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46253f65057015418cb4a6b4e11), 600V 10A). On the reverse side of the board there's a controller IC for the FETs, but there's a thick conformal coating and it has stripped off all the laser markings.

I understand everything that is happening after the transformer. What's baffling me a little is the transformer primary. I tried measuring the voltage across the primary with a multimeter in 600V range, and got an OL reading in both AC and DC modes. Looking nearby, there's an RC snubber circuit across the primary side, and those components are 1kV rated. There are no rear-side components in that area.

[image: Close-up of primary driver section with annotations]

This has left me rather confused. Given the layout, what I was expecting to see is a two-switch supply design, in the manner of a forward converter, with a 320V square wave across the primary side. The two diodes on the front side would align with such a topology.

*(side note: I was under the impression that two-switch designs don't generally need snubbers, but then again this board is clearly designed with extreme attention to EMI suppression, so perhaps they included it out of an abundance of caution)*

Since the only thing feeding into that part of the circuit is the rectified mains, at 320V DC, I'm somewhat confused as to how the voltage across the transformer primary is coming back as over 600V (my guess is 2×Vpk = 640V).

The transformer appears to be custom made for this board, so I have no idea what the winding configuration is for it. It could be two primary windings, but I'm now wondering if the center taps could be for a magnetising inductor, which could mean that this is an LC resonant converter. The secondary side for the 13V rails would make sense in that context, but I've never seen such a design with a full-bridge rectifier running off separate taps of the same transformer. It also doesn't really explain why over 600V appears across the outer taps.

I'm at a bit of a loss here. What's going on?

Comment: Nice work. + 1.

Comment: The PFC should create a DC rail of 360-380V across the electros. Your block diagram is not quite correct as the chain is main in, filter, rectify, PFC (boost converter - switch, inductor, diode) then the rail electros then the main converter. It could very well be the main converter is a resonant one. Being a large screen the psu is a few 100Watts whereas the small screens usually get by with a flyback converter using one mosfet. Looking at the transformer size and power, I’d lay money it is a resonant converter. There’s ics available now that make this solution trivial.

Comment: Would a resonant converter explain the 600V across the primary?

Comment: Are you going to remove the inductors and transformers to measure their resistance and inductance so you can get a better picture and perhaps run simulations to figure more out? Very interesting. Too bad they obscured the controller ic. Thanks for letting us know what you found out.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD I'll be honest, I have pretty heavy ADHD and the repair job is complete (the fault itself was interesting on its own - poorly spec'd ESD/EMI suppression packages leading to shoot-through on SMPS transients, heating shunt resistors, leading to more overshoot, in a loop, until the TVS diodes shorted and popped the shunts for good), so even though I have a spare functioning power board my chances of doing extensive teardown and analysis work on it is not particularly high. If I ever get around to buying a 1kV capable DMM in the future I might come back to this as a test case.

Comment: @Polynomial -- Very cool.  I have ADHD as well, so I feel for you. Thanks for letting me know the fault progression. That was interesting, too.

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD No worries. Hopefully someone stumbles across this and has some insight on why it's measuring like this. In the meantime I might see if I can nerd-snipe Big Clive into letting me ship him a board for an analysis video...

Comment: @Polynomial -- Great idea!